# list with custom type, retrieve attribute as a vector

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of a custom object, called `Atmosphere`. My list contains approximately 10,000 `Atmosphere` objects.
The object has quite a few different attributes. One attribute is `temperature`.

My list,

```
   index    Type
   0        Atmosphere
   1        Atmosphere
   2        Atmosphere
   ...
   n        Atmosphere
```

From this list though I want to get all the temperatures into a vector so I can plot it. What is the best way to do this? I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: Have a look at [map](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#map) function:

```py
myList = [...]
print(list(map(lambda x : x.temperature, myList))
```